# Asynchronous Http server in android

Tags: android, http

I'm implementing an asynchronous HTTP server in Android. I am using the code from the link http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html (Asynchronous HTTP server).  While compiling it I am getting the following errors and the application crashes:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams
```

in the line

```
HttpParams params = new SyncBasicHttpParams();
```

What is the cause and how to resolve it?

I am using the jars from httpcomponents-core-4.3-alpha1.
[image]

Comment: sounds like conflicting imports maybe?

Comment: @alistair3408 Hi, I m using the latest version of the jars. Any idea how it could be resolved?

Comment: Add a screenshots of your project with your libs folder expanded so we can see each jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a beginning of answer on this thread : [What version of Apache HTTP Client is bundled in Android 1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618573/what-version-of-apache-http-client-is-bundled-in-android-1-6)

Indeed the error you get states that the SyncBasicHttpParams class you use is not compatible with the HttpParams class shipped in android. You should try to downgrade your apache libs to 4.0.X as indicated in the thread.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I just found that org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncService is not bundled with Android. Please post your suggestion to a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816537/handling-http-get-delete-android-using-rest. @Snicolas

Comment: There is no link with this question and my answer.

Comment: I meant if you have any ideas of how to make asynchronous(non blocking) HTTP server in Android, post to the above link. Thanks. @Snicolas