# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams

Tags: java, android, apache

Whenever i try to install my app via .apk , i get a crash and logcat shows following stack trace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.sabeeh.helloworld, PID: 24905
>       java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams
>               at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
>               at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
>               at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
>               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
>               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
>               at com.activeandroid.ReflectionUtils.getParsers(ReflectionUtils.java:158)
>               at com.activeandroid.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:100)
>               at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:8)
>               at com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:9)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>   04-15 18:55:44.698

It works fine when played from android studio , I have research heavily over the internet , and most of the answers are from 2 3 years back , in which they have asked to downgrade the apache mime, but older versions lack significant functionality .

Currently i am using these versions:

```
compile files('src/libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
compile files('src/libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('src/libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
```

Please do note , i have already tried downgrading and upgrading libraries.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using version 4.3.6 of httpcore?

Comment: No , just tried to downgrade to see if it works .

Comment: Try using the same version for each jar.

Comment: i did use same versions  
    compile files('src/libs/httpmime-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/httpclient-4.4.1.jar')


still crashing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Http server in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910895/asynchronous-http-server-in-android)

Comment: I did read that question ofcourse , and that is a 2 year old question , it does not solve my problem .